# Appending google sheets with python DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets, append

I try to append the google sheet with python df.
After google sheet authorization, I tried this:

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Sheet1!A1:E100").execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Sheet1!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS", body={"values":df}).execute()
```

but it gives me **TypeError**: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

So I tried this function, which allows to load and overwrite data into google sheet but not to append data:

```
def iter_pd(df):
    for val in df.columns:
        yield val
    for row in df.to_numpy():
        for val in row:
            if pd.isna(val):
                yield ""
            else:
                yield val
    
def pandas_to_sheets(pandas_df, sheet, clear = True):
    # Updates all values in a workbook to match a pandas dataframe
    if clear:
        sheet.clear()
    (row, col) = pandas_df.shape
    cells = sheet.range("A1:{}".format(gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(row + 1, col)))
    for cell, val in zip(cells, iter_pd(pandas_df)):
        cell.value = val
    sheet.update_cells(cells)
   

pandas_to_sheets(df, workbook.worksheet("Sheet1"))
```

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Pandas DataFrame has a to_json method: [see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: Thanks, I ve already tried this, but it gives me this error: https://ibb.co/6sxQ1JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigating I found a method using `df.to_json()` that works for me:

`to_json` returns a string thats json formatted and the sheets api expects a list instead.
So i used this call:

```python
sheet.values().append(
    spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
    range="Sheet1!A1",
    valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
    insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
    body={
        "values": json.loads(df.to_json(orient='values'))
    },
).execute()
```

with `import json` beforehand.

`orient='values'` formats the data as just a values array as required by the sheets api,
`json.loads()` parses the generated json-string into a python object (list)

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

The body parameter in the **request** variable of your code should be in dict type and your dataframe should be converted to json.

### Solution

Your code in your **request** variable should look like this(I replicated this on my end and it is working as expected):

```
request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Sheet1!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS", body={'values':df.to_json()}).execute()
```